# Mongoose bulk inserts & auto-sequence

Tags: mongoose, bulkinsert

I created a mongoose schema with _id as auto-sequence field. When I tried inserting each record  using create,  _id field is incrementing as expected. But, when I use bulk insert to create multiple records, _id values getting saved are the mongodb generated values and are not taken from auto-sequence.

I want to insert records using multiple async bulk inserts, with _id as auto-sequence or auto-increment field

Appreciate any suggestion. Thanks